# serverspec keeps failing on one and only one file

Tags: chef-infra, serverspec

I have a cookbook setting up a Splunk Forwarder.  I've created a number of integration - serverspec tests for the configuration files.  One in particular, `/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/search/local/inputs.conf` keeps failing all the tests the other files are passing.  My code looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe file('/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/search/local/') do
  it { should be_directory }
  it { should be_owned_by 'nobody' }
  it { should be_mode 755 }
end

describe file('/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/') do
  it { should be_directory }
  it { should be_owned_by 'nobody' }
  it { should be_mode 755 }
end

describe file('/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/outputs.conf') do
  it { should exist }
  it { should be_owned_by 'nobody' }
  it { should be_mode 600 }
end

describe file('/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/inputs.conf') do
  it { should exist }
  it { should be_owned_by 'nobody' }
  it { should be_mode 600 }
end

describe file('/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/search/local/inputs.conf}') do
  it { should exist }
  it { should be_owned_by 'nobody' }
  it { should be_mode 600 }
end

describe file('/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/SplunkUniversalForwarder/default/limits.conf') do
  it { should exist }
  it { should be_owned_by 'nobody' }
  it { should be_mode 444 }
end

describe file('/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/web.conf') do
  it { should exist }
  it { should be_owned_by 'nobody' }
  it { should be_mode 600 }
end
```

Every file and directory in this spec file passes except for `/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/search/local/inputs.conf`.  I'm using a Docker instance and Test Kitchen so when I log in I find:

1. The file exists
2. The file is owned by "nobody"
3. The file has 600 permissions

Exactly like several of the other files.  Additionally, I can see from the standard out of my Chef convergence the file getting created with the correct permissions and ownership as well as content.

I've checked to see if one of the parent directories is not owned correctly or has different permissions than the other files that pass but that isn't the case.

I have no idea why this is not passing.

Comment: What is the verbose failure output for that test?

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled and enforcing?  If so, are there any entries in the audit.log for inputs.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that typo in the test is your enemy.

`describe file('/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/search/local/inputs.conf`**}**`') do`

Try to remove that bracket and run test again.